# iOS- CVPixelBufferCreate memory cannot release correctly when making image to video

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory

I am making images into a video. But always crashed because of memory warning, too much allocation on `CVPixelBufferCreate`. I don't know how to handle it right. I've seen a lot of similar topics and none of them solved my problem.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
- (void) writeImagesArray:(NSArray*)array asMovie:(NSString*)path
{
    NSError *error  = nil;
    UIImage *first = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    CGSize frameSize = first.size;
    AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:
                                  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                              error:&error];
    NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);
    
    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithDouble:frameSize.width],AVVideoWidthKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithDouble:frameSize.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                                   nil];
    
    AVAssetWriterInput* writerInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                                       assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                       outputSettings:videoSettings];
    
    self.adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput
                                                     sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];
    
    [videoWriter addInput:writerInput];
    
    //Start Session
    [videoWriter startWriting];
    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];
    
    int frameCount = 0;
    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;
    for(UIImage *img in array)
    {
        buffer = [self newPixelBufferFromCGImage:[img CGImage] andFrameSize:frameSize];
        if (self.adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)
        {
            CMTime frameTime =  CMTimeMake(frameCount,FPS);
            [self.adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
        }
        if(buffer)
            CVPixelBufferRelease(buffer);
        
        frameCount++;
    }
    
    [writerInput markAsFinished];
    [videoWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{
        
        if (videoWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatusFailed) {
            
            NSLog(@"Movie save failed.");
            
        }else{
            
            NSLog(@"Movie saved.");
        }
    }];
    
    NSLog(@"Finished.");
}

        
- (CVPixelBufferRef)newPixelBufferFromCGImage: (CGImageRef) image andFrameSize:(CGSize)frameSize
{
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                             nil];
    
    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;
    
    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                          frameSize.width,
                                          frameSize.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options,
                                          &pxbuffer);
    
    NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);
    
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
    void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);
    NSParameterAssert(pxdata != NULL);
    
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = (CGBitmapInfo) kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst;
    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata,
                                                 frameSize.width,
                                                 frameSize.height,
                                                 8,
                                                 4*frameSize.width,
                                                 rgbColorSpace,
                                                 bitmapInfo);
    
    NSParameterAssert(context);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0));
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image),
                                           CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

    return pxbuffer;
}
```

**UPDATES:**

I made my video into small segments.
After adding a [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.00005]; in the loop.
the memory just magically released.

But, this cause my UI stuck for seconds because of this line. Any better solution?

```
for(UIImage *img in array)
{
    buffer = [self newPixelBufferFromCGImage:[img CGImage] andFrameSize:frameSize];
    //CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, adaptor.pixelBufferPool, &buffer);
    if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)
    {
        CMTime frameTime =  CMTimeMake(frameCount,FPS);
        [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
    }
    
    if(buffer)
        CVPixelBufferRelease(buffer);
    
    frameCount++;
    
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.00005];
}
```

Here's the memory:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a fast review of your code, I can't see anything wrong in the management of the CVBuffer itself.
What I think it could be the source of your issue is the array of UIImages.
UIImage has this behavior, until you request the CGImage property or draw it, the attached image is not decoded in memory, so the impact in memory of unused images is low.
Your enumeration calls the CGImage property on each image and you never get rid of them, this can explain the continue increase of memory allocation.

Comment: Thanks. But, I see no memory problem in images in Instruments. I actually saw the allocation is from CVPixelBufferCreate, and never release correctly..

Comment: I don't know, the buffer is created but released correctly after you use it, have you tried on a real device?

Comment: The time works because probably the buffer is still used by the buffer adapter. I would suggest you to:1 -do not use an image array, but an array of path to your images 2- the buffer adapter has it own timings is preferable if you use _pixelBufferAdaptor.assetWriterInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue: 3-use a CVBufferPool

Comment: I added CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, self.adaptor.pixelBufferPool, &buffer); after CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL, but memory still does a lot allocation and no releases.

Comment: That's pretty weird, but I strongly suggest you to test on device, with or without leaks, your memory impact can be an issue on a real device even when you add a sleep

Comment: Yes, sleep is not a practical solution..I know, still, leaking problem is unsolved. I've also tried to use CVPixelReleasePool.. but the video result are all dark green, cannot figure this problem out neither.

Answer (score 1):

If you not use the `Images` later. You can do it like this:

```
    [images enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIImage * _Nonnull img, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:img.CGImage frameSize:[VDVideoEncodeConfig globalConfig].size];

        CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount, (int32_t)[VDVideoEncodeConfig globalConfig].frameRate);
        frameCount++;
        [_assetRW appendNewSampleBuffer:pixelBuffer pst:frameTime];

        CVPixelBufferRelease(pixelBuffer);
        // This can release the memory
        // The Image.CGImageRef result in the memory leak you see in the Instruments
        images[idx] = [NSNull null];
    }];
```